# Export to PDF and Print to PDF not working 10.4.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, pdf

Has anyone had issues with shapes not appearing when exported to PDF or Print to PDF?

This has been happening a lot lately and I don't understand what the issues is.

[image]

Comment: Not sure if related, but I had polygons that would draw incorrectly depending on how far zoomed in I was. sometimes they drew correctly and other times it would draw the inverse (the polygon would would show up as a donut hole and everything outside of the correct geometry would be filled in!).  I only found out about it when I PDF'd it.  Solution was to run "check geometry" and "repair geometry" on that feature class.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting to a .png or .jpeg.

I have had this same issue in the past.  I have not found rhyme or reason to it.

When I have had random issues exporting to a PDF, I have been able to export to a .png or .jpeg without any problems.  I am not sure what is causing this or how to fix it.